# Responding to "Hide Others" Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, notifications, nsapplication

I am looking for a notification or callback that is similar to `NSWorkspaceDidHideApplicationNotification` for when a user chooses "Hide Others" in any running application.  I was wondering if anyone knows of an api or has some advice in detecting the "Hide Others" action in any application.

Comment: I'd have to ponder a bit on that, but I'm fascinated about what the use case is for this. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I dont think there is a notification for it, It seems kind of un-Mac to care about things that are happening in unrelated applications.

Comment: having said that, you get the applicationWillHide:, as josh stated, and you can intercept the hideOtherApplications: event in your responder chain, that will tell you when your active application is asked to hide other applications.

Answer (score 2):

Your app delegate gets [`applicationWillHide:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW16) and [`applicationDidHide:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW17) whenever your application hides, no matter what caused it.